# Image not loading with hybrid apps resource react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a hybrid app in which I am building some ui in React native and other in native ios. I want to add an image in my view. Image is present in images.xcassets of my project. as per below documentation,
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources

I just need to provide name of the image file and react native should be able to load this image for me. Unfortunately, Image is not loaded in react ui. Document doesn't talk about any constraints for image type or name.

Has anyone faced this problem? any suggestion? Updating document with little more description might be helpful.

React Native version: 0.30
[xcode screenshot with image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7676582/22561042/84aab2c6-e92b-11e6-9304-1178022131ad.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the problem. I was using release version of main.jsbundle and it was suppressing warnings. When I switched to debug main.jsbundle, I saw that my app was giving warning 'native module for RCTImageView' not found.' This is a very standard warning. My app was mission 'RCTImage' as submodule in podfile. After updating my podfile and running pod update, I could render images with static resource of native app(pure ios) using react native.

Steps were, add image to images.xcassets or anywhere else in project and make sure that it's added in "copy bundle resources" list.
Now, use this image as uri: 'imagename' in react native code.